# Javafx TreeTableView - efficient way of updating single row from huge collection

Tags: javafx, treetableview

What's the best way to update a single row at a time from a treetableview with huge collection of rows?
Currently i am storing references of treeitems in a map and accessing the required row by getting it from the map.